# Magento Upgrade : Copiying frontend files

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.8, upgrade

I'm a beginner in Magento, and I'm following the road-map below to upgrade from 1.8 to 1.9 version.

[image]

Arriving to 4th step. I didn't know which directories should i copy from /app/design/frontend

Could Any one Help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your 1.8 instance go to **System > Config > General > Design > Package > Current Package Name** and that is the directory under /app/design/frontend/ that you need to copy over.

To be on the safe side copy over anything that isn't /base or /default or /rwd

Note, if you have modified anything in /base or /default or /rwd you will probably lose these changes when you upgrade to 1.9